# How to link a calculated id with a many to one field in Odoo studio?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13, odoo-domain

I'm working for the first in a new app in odoo, and I have conditionals for several fields so I wanted to use a changing id with a many to one field, in other words my domain is where id=calculated_id which will be only one value, I tried to obtain a string of the name of the many to one field to try it to use it as the context but I retrieved a list of an object similar to [x_model_data(2,)] instead of the desired field value "test 2", I believe that the 2 of the parentheses relates to the calculated id=2

Comment: It looks like a string representation of a list of records. You will need to use `.id` to get the id of a specific record.

Comment: And if I want to get the name?

Comment: You can get all fields with dot notation, If the field `name` is defined use `.name`